# Finding Search Terms from one Pandas Dataframe in another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to search for key terms that are contained in one dataframe in another, returning each one when it is found in the second dataframe.

My code below words to extract the keywords.  However, some of the keywords overlap and it only pulls the first result it finds, when I would like it to pull as many matches as are present:

df1

| id | keyword |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | we are |
| 1 | we |
| 2 | this is |

df2

| id | Sentence | Result [with current code] | Result [what I want] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | we are us | we | **we are, we** |
| 1 | this is who we | this is, we | this is, we |

```
Keywords = df1['Keyword']

s = set(Keywords)
df2['Result'] = df2['Sentence'].apply(lambda x: ', 
'.join(set(x.split()).intersection(s)))
```

I don't need it to be particularly quick, but I would like it to be accurate and give me every related result.

Comment: Honestly, pandas is the wrong tool for the job here and will only get in your way.

Comment: With a regex, you will more likely get `we are` rather than `we are, we`, as regex cannot match at the same position.

Comment: It's not that the strings are overlapping but rather you are searching for only single words (with `x.split()`). I'm surprised that you even got `this is` at the second row. At least your code doesn't give that on my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
df2['result'] = [', '.join([words for words in df1.keyword 
                            if words in sentence]) 
                 for sentence in df2.Sentence]
print(df2)

   id        Sentence       result
0   0       we are us   we are, we
1   1  this is who we  we, this is
```